# error in using getAbsolutePath function in java

Tags: java

My xml file is place in this path "C/users/input/abc.xml".
I am executing code from "c/users/prg/abc.java" 
Using getAbsolutePath function on Xml file object but i am getting this"c/users/prg/abc.xml" as result.

i have already tried using the below code:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\users\\Input\\abc.xml");
    String absPath = file.getAbsolutePath(); 
    System.out.print(absPath);
```

**output:   C\users\prg\abc.xml**

is it Classpath issue? or Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting? `c:/users/prg/abc.xml` is the absolute Path of your xml-File.

Comment: the complete path.. C/usres/Input/abc.xml

Comment: Nah, this should be ok. I suspect you forgot recompiling the Java file, running a different classfile, etc. This seems to be a config issue.

Comment: i have setted path for jdk bin..

Comment: i have setted Env variable path for jdk bin..
Classpath i tried javac -cp ".;/." abc.java
for current dirctory and parent of it 
javac -cp ".;/./Input" abc.java

Comment: Try to check your folders using Windows Explorer, maybe some of your folder is restricted especially most folder in C://.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path is like below

C:\users\Input\abc.xml

Once again rebuild ur application. What your expecting from us.

Regards,
Sekhar

Answer (score -1):

I Think the error is occurring due to wrong class path.

Check the class path if it is right and let me know.

Comment: while a good guess could be an answer, this would fit much better as a comment

Comment: i have setted Env variable path for jdk bin..
Classpath i tried javac -cp ".;/." abc.java
for current dirctory and parent of it 
javac -cp ".;/./Input" abc.java

getting correct output if i am using complete path for file object. if i need to use only filename and want to get absolute path.. how should i set the calss path